# How to define a foreign key relation with an abstract model?

Tags: python, django, class, inheritance, django-models

Having this code:

```
class Part:
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name of part"),
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_("Name of the part.")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Part")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Parts")
        abstract = True


class Book(Part):
    isbn = models.CharField(
        help_text=_("The ISBN of the book"),
        max_length=15
    )
```

for my models. I next step I need to link to the basic object. Done with this code:

```
class StorageItem(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(
        Part,
        help_text=_("The part stored at this spot.")
    )
```

I'm getting this error message:

> ERRORS: StorageItem.part: (fields.E300) Field defines
>   a relation with model 'Part', which is either not installed, or is
>   abstract.

What is the correct approach to link an object to a group of different classes all derived from one base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to add `ForeignKeys` to abstract models. One way to get around this limitation is to use `GenericForeignKey`:

```
class StorageItem(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Then you can use the GenericForeignKey as follows:

```
book = Book.objects.create(name='test', isbn='-')
item = StorageItem(content_object=book)
item.save()
item.content_object # <Book>
```

A quick explanation of how this works:

- `content_type` stores the model that generic foreign key points to
- `object_id` stores the id of the model
- `content_object` is a shortcut for directly accessing the linked foreign key object

The docs provide additional information on how to use this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

**Edit**

Upon further research, it looks like [django_polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic) may also do what you want.

Comment: It looks like  django_polymorphic is what I was looking for at the end.  Not sure whether it will be the best one in a few month, but so far ;)